# Alert JavaScript con Temporizador

Tags: javascript, aplicación-web

Como puedo hacer para crear un Alert  en JavaScript que se vea por 2 segundos y luego cierre automaticamente (solo) sin que el usuario haga click en aceptar?

Comment: Considera marcar alguna de las excelentes respuestas que te han dado como aceptada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo lo hago con la funcion setTimeout. De la siguiente forma.

```js
$('#alert').fadeIn();     
  setTimeout(function() {
       $("#alert").fadeOut();           
  },2000);
```

Comment: Hola ¿Cómo se haría ese mismo código pero en javascript puro?

Answer (score 7):

Te presento a `Toastr`, es una librería en `JavaScript` que genera notificaciones de una manera "*moderna*":

```js
toastr.options = {
  "debug": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
  "onclick": null,
  "fadeIn": 300,
  "fadeOut": 100,
  "timeOut": 5000,
  "extendedTimeOut": 1000
}

var showToastrs = false;

function toastrs() {
  if (!showToastrs) {
    toastr.error('Estamos bajo ataque DDoS', 'Error Critico!');
    toastr.success('Se guardaron los cambios satisfactoriamente', 'Todo en orden');
    toastr.warning('La latencia del server esta aumentando.', 'Alerta!');
  } else {
    toastr.error('no se puede!\'t.', 'Otro error crítico');
  }
}

// Definimos los callback cuando el TOAST le da un fade in/out:
toastr.options.onFadeIn = function() {
  showToastrs = true;
};
toastr.options.onFadeOut = function() {
  showToastrs = false;
};

$(function() {
  $("#clear").on("click", function() {
    // Clears the current list of toasts
    toastr.clear();
  });
  $("#rewind").on("click", function() {
    // show toastrs :)
    toastrs();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://codeseven.github.com/toastr/toastr.js"></script>
<link href="http://codeseven.github.com/toastr/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://codeseven.github.com/toastr/toastr-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html" target="_blank">Toastr official demo</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="clear" type="submit" value="Limpiar notificaciones">
<input id="rewind" type="submit" value="Mostrar notificaciones">
```

Comment: Esto es cool, no conocía Toastr, mucho gusto! =), creo que esto lo usare en algunos proyectos! gracias por la información.

Comment: de nada @Elenasys, estamos para servir :D

Answer (score 4):

Veo que quieres abrir y cerrar el mensaje, con Javascript esto no se puede realizar, el cerrar el mensaje tiene que ser manualmente.

Como otra opción es mostrar una ventana con el mensaje y cerrarla automáticamente después de 2 segundos (2000 ms).

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Abre un mensaje que se cerrara en 2 segundos.</p>

<button onclick="ejecutaAlerta()">muestra mensaje</button>

<script>
function ejecutaAlerta() {   
var w = window.open('','','width=100,height=100')
w.document.write('Hola StackOverflow!')
w.focus()
setTimeout(function() {w.close();}, 2000)
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Quien realiza el llamado de la funcion es el método [setTimeOut()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp):

> **setTimeout()** Ejecuta una funcion, despues de esperar durante un numero
>   especifico de milisegundos.

Comment: el OP quiere otra cosa, quiere que el mensaje permanezca dos segundos visible, y no en cambio que tarde dos segundos en aparecer.

Comment: Gracias, he eliminado la segunda opción que no cumplia con lo que requiere el OP.

Answer (score 3):

Otra opción que te puede servir es [`JQuery jGrowl`](https://github.com/stanlemon/jGrowl)

Te dejo un ejemplo con una duración de 2 segundos:

```js
$.jGrowl("Hello world!",{ life : 2000});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jgrowl/1.4.1/jquery.jgrowl.min.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jgrowl/1.4.1/jquery.jgrowl.min.js"></script>
```

si requieres algo más "moderno" te recomiendo [`toastr`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/21468/6635)

Answer (score 3):

Me gusta la solución de @fredyfx pero si te importa la velocidad de carga y los recursos utilizados por tu app puedes implementar algo similar en menos bytes poniendo solo las funciones que vas a usar.

Este es un ejemplo, claro que los estilos los puedes ajustar a la estética de tu aplicación y puedes agregar mas features. Esta es una base para escribir tu propio componente sin tener que cargar largas librerías que resultan en aplicaciones pesadas.

```js
(function(window, document) { // asilamos el componente
  // creamos el contedor de las tostadas o la tostadora
  var container = document.createElement('div');
  container.className = 'toast-container';
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  
  // esta es la funcion que hace la tostada
  window.doToast = function(message) {
    // creamos tostada
    var toast = document.createElement('div');
    toast.className = 'toast-toast';
    toast.innerHTML = message;

    // agregamos a la tostadora
    container.appendChild(toast);    

    // programamos su eliminación
    setTimeout(function() {
      // cuando acabe de desaparecer, lo eliminamos del dom.
      toast.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
         container.removeChild(toast);
      }, false);

      // agregamos un estilo que inicie la "transition". 
      toast.classList.add("fadeout");      
    }, 2000); // OP dijo, "solo dos segundos"
  }
})(window, document);

// ejempo de uso
doToast("Hola mundo!");

// ejemplo retardado de uso
setTimeout(function() {
   doToast("Soy una tostada");
}, 1200);
```

```css
.toast-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 150px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10; /* sobre todo lo demás */
}

.toast-toast {
  font-size: 250%;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px green;
  background: #98FF98;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;  
  transition: all 0.5s; 
}

.fadeout{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: como dirían en tu tierra: sos un capo :D

Answer (score 2):

Con el alert estandar de javascript dudo que puedas realizarlo, pero si usas un alert implementado desde jquery como ser

[jqAlert](http://jqalert.com/doc/)

veras en el ejemplo que implementar un `timer`, por ejemplo el del titulo `Alert Dialogs` define

```
$.alert('jqAlert is easy to use with alerts and its where I got my start.', {
    title:'Alert Title Message',
    icon:'',
    customIcon:'icon-asterisk',
    exception: 'Exception',
    stack: 'Stack Trace',
    timer:5000,
    onTimeout:function() { },
    onClose: function() { },
    buttons:[
        {
            title:'Press Me',
            callback:function() { $(this).dialog("close");}
        }
    ]
});
```

veras el `timer:5000` despues de ese tiempo se cierra solo

Answer (score 0):

Yo realice esto para el evento de un submit:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {


    const clicked = localStorage.getItem('btn-clicked');

    checkImgBtnClicked();

    function checkImgBtnClicked() {

        if (clicked) {
            document.getElementById('btn').disabled = true;

            saveClicked();

            setTimeout(() => {

                // Crear una alerta
                const alertaExito = document.createElement('P');
                alertaExito.classList.add('auth__warning', 'mt-3');
                alertaExito.textContent = 'Debes de esperar para volver a envíar otro correo.';

                formulario.appendChild(alertaExito);

                setTimeout(() => {
                    alertaExito.remove();
                }, 400000);
            }, 50);

            removeAlert();

        } else {
            document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', saveClicked);
        }


    }

    function saveClicked() {
        localStorage.setItem('btn-clicked', 'true');
        setTimeout(function() {
            localStorage.clear();
        }, 300000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            location.reload(true);
        }, 300000);
    }

    

    function removeAlert() {
       
        setTimeout(function() {
            
            document.getElementById('alert').remove();
        }, 8000);
    }


});
```

Este es el submit es el envío de correo de verificación en Laravel

```
<form id="formulario" class="text-center" method="POST" action="{{ route('verification.resend') }}">
@csrf

<button id="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-center mb-3">Da click aquí para enviarte otro correo</button>
```