# ventana emergente y redirección en aplicación web

Tags: php, javascript, mensajes

Tengo un tema que no se como resolver y espero me puedan orientar.

Tengo un sistema en `PHP`, necesito mandar un mensaje de error y hacer una dirección sin que el usuario tenga que intervenir, es decir, que en cierto tiempo la redirección se haga en automático.

Lo hacia con `javascript`,(`alert` y `location`) pero `alert` exige que se le de un clic en el botón de aceptar.

En el sistema los usuarios pasan un código de barras que les muestra en pantalla el menú antes elegido para comer, si un usuario pasa 2 veces su credencial, el sistema debe informar que ese menú ya fue entregado, y continuar preparado para recibir el siguiente código de barras. Es por eso que el mensaje debe aparecer para informar del problema durante un tiempo y no entorpecer la lectura de otros códigos de barra. El único medio de entrada en este punto es un lector de código de barras.

¿Hay alguna manera que me puedan recomendar para hacer esto?

Comment: Que hagas tu propio alert desde Javascript y cuando lo muestres inicies el temporalizador para la redirección

Comment: Revisa esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21460/alert-javascript-con-temporizador

Comment: Muéstranos el código que tienes y en que está fallando. Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas.

Una de ellas usando solo PHP mediante 
`header('Location: http://tuweb.com/pagina.html');`

En este caso el mensaje se daría en la pantalla destino.

La otra forma es mediante javascript
`window.location.href= 'http://tuweb.com/pagina.html'`

Espero te sriva!!

Comment: Creo que esto no le servirá, ya que él necesita mostrar un alert previamente

Comment: El alert se podría hacer de muchas formas, por ejemplo jquery-confirm, alert de bootstrap, etc, etc. El tema es si es necesario que el usuario presione confirmar o no. Sino para que sería el mensaje?

Comment: Hola. Recuerda hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas como responder a preguntas de baja calidad. La pregunta no es del todo clara y tu respuesta, _al menos desde mi punto de vista_, no parece solucionar por completo la duda del OP.